# Installing pgroonga on macosx (with Postgres.app)

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm just following the instructions [here](https://pgroonga.github.io/install/macos.html) for installing the pgroonga add-on for Postgres but when I get to this step:

`% psql -d pgroonga_test --command 'CREATE EXTENSION pgroonga;'`

I get the following error:

`ERROR: could not open extension control file "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/share/postgresql/extension/pgroonga.control": No such file or directory`

I assume it's looking in the wrong location since I installed Postgres with the app and pgroonga using brew. I also tried building pgroonga from source and completely re-installing Postgres. Nothing seems to work.

If anyone could point me into the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. And thanks in advance for helping out a newb!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If PostgreSQL is newly installed, don't forget to start PostgreSQL

```
$ brew services start postgresql
```

For PostgreSQL installation with `Homebrew`, there is [a good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula/4158763#4158763).

In my case, I installed [postgresapp](https://postgresapp.com).
My `postgresapp` location is `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/xxx/`.

And I installed PGroonga by Homebrew:`$ brew install pgroonga`.
My PGroonga directory is `/usr/local/Cellar/pgroonga/xxx`.

I manually put pgroonga lib in `postgresapp` extensions folder. I copy all files as following

1. /usr/local/Cellar/pgroonga/xxx/share/postgresql ->
   /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/xxx/share/postgresql
2. /usr/local/Cellar/pgroonga/xxx/lib ->
   /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/xxx/lib/postgresql

Restart `postgresapp`.
Now ready to install pgroonga extension into the database with [pgadmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/extension_dialog.html) GUI.

Comment: After trying this solution, I'm now getting : `ERROR: could not load library "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/lib/postgresql/pgroonga.so": dlopen(/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/lib/postgresql/pgroonga.so, 10): Symbol not found: _build_reloptions Referenced from: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/lib/postgresql/pgroonga.so Expected in: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/postgres in /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/lib/postgresql/pgroonga.so`.

Do you have an idea what this is? thank you.

Answer (score 5):

When you build from sources, make sure your PATH contains PostgresApp binary installation:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
$ which pg_config
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config
```

Now you can build the extension from sources and `make install` should install the files in the location expected by PostgresApp.